# Do dataframe columns need to have the same number of elements with a datetime index?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I know that pandas data frames can have NaN values. I mean specifically if I am creating a dataframe from a list of lists of various sizes. Do the columns that do not have as many rows as the longest column get filled with NaNs automatically? How would this be affected if I used a datetime index?

Comment: A simplification, but a `DatetimeIndex` is nothing more than an Index with some special methods and attributes (i.e. `.year`) that make sense with dates and times. Internally, the dates are stored as `int64` values so it's really not that much different from a RangeIndex.

Comment: why dont you try it

Comment: I had to read some more documentation in order to better understand this, It's much easier to use NaNs and not worry about it. I am moving to SQLServer soon so this will not be relevant, thanks for the explanations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = ['ed1','ed2','ed3','ed4']
list3 = ['example']
list_date_index = ['2000-01-01', '1999-12-20', '2000-11-01', '1995-02-25', '1992-06-30']

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index':list_date_index,'list1': list1, 'list2': list2, 'list3': list3}, orient='index').T

df=df.set_index(datetime_index)
df.drop('index',axis=1,inplace=True)

print(df2.index)
df.head()
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2000-01-01', '1999-12-20', '2000-11-01', '1995-02-25',
               '1992-06-30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

            list1   list2    list3
2000-01-01  1        ed1    example
1999-12-20  2        ed2    None
2000-11-01  3        ed3    None
1995-02-25  None     ed4    None
1992-06-30  None    None    None
```

*edit: datetime index passing the datetime series